# Prepend a command in Start-Process to provide "y" input to Plink

Tags: powershell, ssh, plink, start-process

I saw a solution to cache a server host key by adding the command just below on the top of my script before running the other Plink tasks.

```
& "echo y | C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -batch -i $PrivateKeyPath $username "exit" 2>&1
```

Error message:

> The term 'echoy| C:\ProgramFiles\PuTTY\plink.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,...

So the spaces prior the pipe symbol are removed and therefore the command is not recognized.

My other attempt is to use `Start-Process` but I do not know how I am able to prepend `echo y |` to the plink.exe path.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe' -Argumentlist "-ssh -batch -i $PrivateKeyPath $username $command 2>&1"
```

Is there an option to prepend something to the `-FilePath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not blindly answer "y" to Plink host key verification prompt. You lose a protection against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You should use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) with your host key fingerprint.

Similarly for `pscp`: [Using echo y as an automated response to a pcp hostkey prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39924091/850848)

Answer (score 0):

`& "echo y | C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"` makes `echo y |` part of the path to the executable.

Change this:

```
& "echo y | C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -batch -i $PrivateKeyPath $username "exit" 2>&1
```

into this:

```
echo 'y' | & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe' -ssh -batch -i $PrivateKeyPath $username "exit" 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I do not receive my original error message but the server key is still not cached.